# Select distinct with group by and having in HQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

In my java project, I need to do an HQL query

Here's my HQL query:

```
select count(distinct n.id)" +
            "  FROM Neighborhood n, NeighborhoodMeta meta, NeighborhoodAffordability aff, AirbnbProperty as ap" +
            "  WHERE n.id = meta.id AND n.id = aff.id AND n.id = ap.neighborhood AND aff.singleHomeValue!=null" +
            " AND (latitude >=:minLat AND latitude <=:maxLat)" +
            " AND (longitude >=:minLong " + (meridian180WithinDistance ? "OR" : "AND") + " longitude <=:maxLong) AND " +
            "acos(sin(:locationLatitude) * sin(radians(latitude)) + cos(:locationLatitude) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) -:locationLongitude)) <=:R " +
            "GROUP BY ap.neighborhood having count(ap.id) > 19
```

this count always produce a "1" result, however, if I deleted the last line of query, it returns a correct result, but I need to limit my results upon the having condition above.

Could anybody help?

Comment: first you should understand that if the 4 entities are linked then you must use inner join,
currently you are using cross product which may decrease your performance.

second try to specify latitude , longitude properties from which entity
like if they are from AirbnbProperty then 
ap.latitude >=:minLat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting only `1`s because you're selecting count of the distinct values which you use for grouping (`n.id = ap.neighborhood`, so `n.id` is the same as `ap.neighborhood`).

I assume the goal of your query is the count of different `Neighborhood`s which are associated with more than 19 `AirbnbProperty`s (after all of the other criteria are applied of course). If so, what you need is basically this:

```
select count(*) from
 (select n.id
   from
   ... the rest of your query without group by ...
   group by n.id having count(ap.id) > 19
 )
```

However, Hibernate does not support subqueries in the `from` clause, so you will have to workaround it with the `in` operator:

```
select count(*) from Neighborhood n
 where n.id in 
  (select n.id
    from
    ... the rest of your query without group by ...
    group by n.id having count(ap.id) > 19
  )
```